# Require only returning module data after delay - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I am working on a project using node.js, and I've encountered this really weird bug where another module I am requiring isn't returning anything.

```
var attack = require('../attacks.js');

function doStuff(){
attack.fireprojectile();
}
```

if I run this, it returns that attack.fireprojectile() is not a function. Which I know is not the case because I use that function in other modules and it works with no issues.

console.logging "attack" shows that it is equal to undefined, meaning that it is not returning anything at all

However, if I change the code to look like this

```
var attack;

setTimeout(function(){
    attack = require('../attacks.js');
}, 200);

function doStuff(){
attack.fireprojectile();
}
```

it works and causes no errors when run

what are the reasons why a module may return nothing when required on startup, and then only work if required after a delay?

the attack.js script contains some code to read data from files, maybe that is related? I don't want to include the entire script because it is 400 lines of code long

EDIT: Attack module structure psuedo code

```
var projectiles = [];

var projectileData = readFile("path to file");

var projectile = function(x, y){
//uses projectile data
//runs projectile object
}

function fireProjectile(){
projectiles.push(new projectile());
}

module.exports = {fireProjectile};
```

Comment: can you share a snippet of how the `attack.js` module is structured. especially the `export` section, as it may have pointers to why this is happening

Comment: You may have a circular dependency here

Comment: Okay I did that